# Next tab completion item

Tags: autocompletion

I was seeing how the different default colorschemes look like in vim. To do that I typed `:colo`, then space and tab. But then when I want to set the next one, I have to press tab a lot of times to get to the next one (and remember the name of the current one).

Is there a faster way to get to the "next" item in a tab completion?

Comment: Does `:set wildmenu` work better for you?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I already have wildmenu set. But if I do `:colo desert` for example. Then after experimenting with that I will type `:` and press up, the arrows or tab or `crtl+n*` doesn't work anymore. So I'd have to `ctrl+w` to delete desert and press tab a bunch of times to get to elflord.

Comment: @BLayer same? I can use wildmenu as intended. Maybe my question is not clear enough? After I enter a command that I used tab for, I wish to be able to repeat with the next item from the tab completion instead, and I'm asking how to do it, if it can be done, without having to press tab a bunch of times to find next item.

Comment: Your first comment threw me. Makes it sound like things are all out of whack with certain keys not working anymore and such. Anyways, the way I read your original question, I'm 99% certain you're not going to find an alternative to pressing tab multiple times. Best bet is to see if any of the `'wildmode'` alternatives make things easier for you...but that'd be an incremental improvement at best.